# very stanger order id, what is the cause for it

Tags: magento-1.9

our system is magento 1.9, i found a stranger order#, 100005583, what is the reason?

[image]

Thank you

SongS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone first visits the site and goes off to a payment gateway they reserve an order ID. If they then do not complete the order it is possible to return much later pick up the reserved order ID when they log into their old basket again and complete the order.

Reason  order IDs are reserved is to maintain any references that might be in a payment gateway.

For example if someone experiences payment issues you dont want to then reissue that order ID to someone else.

Comment: Yes. This could be a reason. And it can be verified relatively eazy. You can check the db and see the creation date of the quote associated to that order. Or its id. If it's way older than the others of the orders placed around the same time as this order, then this explains it.

Comment: well you are correct this customer create account in 2016 and first order is yesterday. july 23